# Joining 2 mysql table and ordering by number of same rows in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need some help with a mysql query.

I have 2 tables,

### Table 1 - Photos (photo_id, photo_url)

1----- www.someurl.com
2----- www.someurl.com
3----- www.someurl.com
4----- www.someurl.com

### Table 2 - Favorites (favorite_id, user_id,photo_id)

1-------5------1
2-------5------2
3-------6------1
4-------6------3
5-------7------2
6-------7------3
7-------8------3
7-------8------4

I want to get results from photos table ordering by the favorite numbers of users.

Correct ordering must be:

1) Photo-3 (3 votes)
2) Photo-2 (2 votes)
2) Photo-1 (2 votes)
2) Photo-4 (1 vote)

Comment: `+1` for giving sample data with desired result :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.photo_url, COUNT(b.photo_ID) totalVotes
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.photo_ID = b.photo_id
GROUP BY a.photo_url
ORDER BY totalVotes DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80411/1)

Comment: thanks for your quick resulting answer. how can i split the results into pages? i mean, listing 10 results per page. how can i put the "where" tag in the sql

Comment: you should be using `LIMIT` for `pagination` this link can help you, http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm